# How to deal with pickling error when pickling very large object

Tags: python, pickle

Got this error when pickling a hundred-GB level object. Any solutions?

```
PicklingError: memo id too large for LONG_BINPUT
```

The code triggered this is the regular `pickle.dump` functionality:

```
pickle.dump(obj, open("obj.pkl", "wb"))
```

Comment: In short, pickle isn't designed for large objects. Using json.dumps() sometimes works better. Using a database is often an even better idea, though this requires some setup.